# how to add already available child entity to new parent entity in hibernate, Java

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am very much new to hibernate and so I am confused with OneToOne, OneToMany unidirectional and bidirectional mappings.

I have two entities: User and Account (A user can contain many accounts). I also have two services, one to add an account and another to add a user. Now I can able to add an account without a user, so that user_id column in the Account table is null. Now when the client wants to add a user he needs to map existing account. So he is able to add the existing account but the user_id column in the account is not updating, it is still in null. 
This is now causing a problem. If I want to retrieve user from the database, then the accounts are not getting retrieved for the user. I suspect that this issue is due to the user_id column is null.

My User Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "QT_USER")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private long userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Account.class)
    private Set<Account> accounts;

    // getter and setter methods
}
```

My Account Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "QT_ACCOUNT")
public class Account implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_ID")
    private long accountId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = true, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    //getter and setter methods
}
```

Can anyone explain me what OneToMany and ManyToOne , JoinColumn annotations are doing here. All I want is, an account can be added to the database table without a user entity, but when a user is being added, the selected account needs to be mapped in the database and when the user is retrieved, details of the user and the its mapped accounts have to be retrieved. But when we retrieve Accounts, users need not be visual.

Comment: Have you tried removing 'updatable = false' from your JoinColumn annotation on the Account entity? When it is set to false, the documentation states that the join column will not be included in any SQL 'UPDATE' statements.

Comment: Yes, I tried setting updatable to 'true'. But no change